# ¿Cómo calcular el porcentaje en una calculadora Python con la función eval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, porcentaje

He escrito una calculadora en python con PyQt5 y hasta el momento todas las operaciones las realiza correctamente menos la de porcentaje, para la evaluación de datos utilizo eval,agradezco su ayuda.
El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
import sys, math

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

# Cargar archivo ui
form_class = uic.loadUiType("Calculadora02.ui")[0]


def num(self, s):
    self.pantallaresultado.insertPlainText(s)


def operador(self, op):
    div = self.pantallaresultado.toPlainText()
    if (validarExpresion(div)):
        nuevo = div + op
        pantalla(self, nuevo)


def pantalla(self, a):
    self.pantallaresultado.clear()
    self.pantallaresultado.insertPlainText(a)


def validarExpresion(div):
    ultimo = div[len(div) - 1]
    simbolos = "+-*/.%"
    encontro = True
    for i in range(len(simbolos)):
        if (simbolos[i] == ultimo):
            encontro = False
            break
    return encontro


def calcular(self, div):
    if (len(div) > 2):
        resultado = eval(str(div))
        pantalla(self, str(resultado))

    else:
        pantalla(self, "Ingrese una expresion para calcular:")


class MyWindowClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btnuno)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btndos)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.btntres)
        self.btn4.clicked.connect(self.btncuatro)
        self.btn5.clicked.connect(self.btncinco)
        self.btn6.clicked.connect(self.btnseis)
        self.btn7.clicked.connect(self.btnsiete)
        self.btn8.clicked.connect(self.btnocho)
        self.btn9.clicked.connect(self.btnnueve)
        self.btn0.clicked.connect(self.btncero)
        self.btnpunto.clicked.connect(self.btnpnto)
        self.btnporcentaje.clicked.connect(self.btnprcentaje)
        self.btnmas.clicked.connect(self.btnms)
        self.btnmenos.clicked.connect(self.btnmnos)
        self.btnmultiplicasion.clicked.connect(self.btnmltiplicasion)
        self.btndivision.clicked.connect(self.btndvision)
        self.btndescontar.clicked.connect(self.btndscontar)
        self.btnclear.clicked.connect(self.btnlimpiar)
        self.btnpar1.clicked.connect(self.btnparuno)
        self.btnpar2.clicked.connect(self.btnpardos)
        self.btnpotencia.clicked.connect(self.btnptencia)
        self.btnraiz.clicked.connect(self.btnriz)
        self.btncalcular.clicked.connect(self.btnclcular)

    # Evento de los botones del 1-0 y parentesis
    def btnuno(self):
        return num(self, "1")

    def btndos(self):
        return num(self, "2")

    def btntres(self):
        return num(self, "3")

    def btncuatro(self):
        return num(self, "4")

    def btncinco(self):
        return num(self, "5")

    def btnseis(self):
        return num(self, "6")

    def btnsiete(self):
        return num(self, "7")

    def btnocho(self):
        return num(self, "8")

    def btnnueve(self):
        return num(self, "9")

    def btncero(self):
        return num(self, "0")

    def btnparuno(self):
        return num(self, "(")

    def btnpardos(self):
        return num(self, ")")

    def btnpnto(self):
        return num(self, ".")

    def btnprcentaje(self):
        p = self.pantallaresultado.toPlainText()
        r=p
        pantalla(self,str(r))

    def btnms(self):
        return num(self, "+")

    def btnmnos(self):
        return num(self, "-")

    def btnmltiplicasion(self):
        return num(self, "*")

    def btndvision(self):
        return num(self, "/")

    def btndscontar(self):
        p = self.pantallaresultado.toPlainText()
        pa = ""
        for i in range(len(p)):
            if (i == (len(p) - 1)):
                pa += ""
            else:
                pa += p[i]
                pantalla(self, str(pa))

    def btnlimpiar(self):
        self.pantallaresultado.clear()

    def btnclcular(self):
        div = self.pantallaresultado.toPlainText()
        calcular(self, div)

    def btnptencia(self):
        p = self.pantallaresultado.toPlainText()
        r = pow(float(p), 2)
        pantalla(self, str(r))

    def btnriz(self):
        p = self.pantallaresultado.toPlainText()
        r = math.sqrt(float(p))
        pantalla(self, str(r))

        # Evento cerrar ventana

    def closeEvent(self):
        # Your desired functionality here
        print('Close button pressed')
        import sys
        sys.exit(0)

    def buttonClicked(self, e):
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Events - Slot', 'click en Button 1.')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, '¡¡¡Advertencia!!!', "Realmente desea cerrar la aplicacion",
                                     QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainCalculadora02 = MyWindowClass(None)
MainCalculadora02.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: ¿cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: Como podría validar el evento de calcular porcentaje en esta calculadora?                                                                                       def btnprcentaje(self):
        p = self.pantallaresultado.toPlainText()
        r=p
        pantalla(self,str(r))

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con validar?, por ejemplo pon casos que son válidos e indica porque lo son, y lo mismo con los casos invalidos. la validez depende de como lo defina.

Comment: Por ejemplo al presionar el usuario de la calculadora  1000*10 y presione el boton % este deberia de realizar el calculo de porcentaje pero me arroja el siguiente error:    /home/afal3d/PycharmProjects/Curso/venv/bin/python /home/afal3d/PycharmProjects/Curso/Calculadora02.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/afal3d/PycharmProjects/Curso/Calculadora02.py", line 116, in btnprcentaje
    r=float((p)/100)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: es que porcentaje es un operador de formato: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting, por ello esta intentando calcular, lo que debes hacer es verificar si existe el caracter "%" y separarlos, asi puede operar el lado izquierdo y el lado derecho y al final calculas: `resp = izq*derecho/100`, pero esto se puede complicar si tiene operaciones combinadas, sospecho que ya existe una libreria que implementa ello, intenta buscar, quizas sympy.

Comment: Podrías indicarme un ejemplo dela solución planteada?

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente seria:

```
num1 = input("Número: ")
num2 = input("Porcentagem: ")

def porcentagem(num1, num2):
    n1 = int(num1)
    n2 = int(num2)

    res = eval("n1 * n2 / 100)")

    print(f"{n1} x {n2}% = {res}")

porcentagem(num1, num2)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice de esta manera sin necesidad de complicarse tanto.

1. Primero tomamos la entrada de datos

Ejemplo: caso el usuario pondría 100*10%

2. Separamos el 100 y el 10 en diferentes variables
   Variable 1= 100
   Variable 2= 10
3. Hacemos la operación para sacar el porcentaje con las variables 1 y 2

Todo esto sería:

```py
def porcentaje():
    global operacion
    shearch= operacion.find("*")# busca en que posicion se encuentra el simbolo multiplicar
    digitos1= operacion[0:shearch] # guardamos los primeros digitos antes del simbolo multicar
    digitos2=operacion[shearch+1:] # guardamos  digitos despues del simbolo multicar
    try:
        mult_int= (int(digitos1)*int(digitos2)/100) # se hace la operacion de porcentaje con numero enteros
        numeroPantalla.set(mult_int)
    except :    
        mult_float= (float(digitos1)* float(digitos2)/100)
        numeroPantalla.set(mult_float)
```